# How to start Quartz in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, quartz.net

I have the following class

```
 public class MyEmailService
 {
    public async Task<bool> SendAdminEmails()
    {
        ...
    }
    public async Task<bool> SendUserEmails()
    {
        ...
    }

 }
 public interface IMyEmailService
 {
    Task<bool> SendAdminEmails();
    Task<bool> SendUserEmails();
 }
```

I have installed the latest [Quartz 2.4.1 Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/) as I wanted a lightweight scheduler in my web app without a separate SQL Server database.

I need to schedule the methods

- `SendUserEmails` to run every week on Mondays 17:00,Tuesdays 17:00 & Wednesdays 17:00
- `SendAdminEmails` to run every week on Thursdays 09:00, Fridays 9:00

What code do I need to schedule these methods using Quartz in ASP.NET Core? I also need to know how to start Quartz in ASP.NET Core as all code samples on the internet still refer to previous versions of ASP.NET.

I can [find a code sample](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net) for the previous version of ASP.NET  but I don't know how to start Quartz in ASP.NET Core to start testing.
Where do I put the `JobScheduler.Start();` in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Why are you even planning on running recurring background tasks in an ASP.NET application? Did you know that this is a terribly wrong approach? See here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/ And then consider moving this logic outside of your ASP.NET application. For example you could use a console app that is scheduled to run at the desired intervals by the OS scheduler. Or alternatively write it as a service that will run and use Quartz to schedule the tasks inside.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I could find no code sample on the internet for ASP.NET Core that explains the  equivalent of `JobScheduler.Start();` in http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net  The scheduling I should be able to resolve but the starting of Quartz is a mystery in ASP.NET Core. Google finds nothing

Comment: see https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/355

Comment: @Set I saw this as well but this is from a year ago meaning it does support it but on internet there is no code sample of how Quartz works in ASP.NET Core

Comment: Maybe a late comment, but I see that you use version 2.4.1 of the NuGet package. It doesn't target .NET Core, IMHO. You should be looking at version 3 (https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/2016/08/16/quartznet-3.0-alpha1-released.html), there are alpha packages available (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/3.0.0-alpha2). Also, migration guide (https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/migration-guide.html) and version 3.x tutorial (https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/index.html) can shed some light.

Answer (score 78):

### TL;DR (full answer can be found below)

Assumed tooling: Visual Studio 2017 RTM, .NET Core 1.1, .NET Core SDK 1.0, SQL Server Express 2016 LocalDB.

In web application .csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <!-- .... existing contents .... -->

  <!-- add the following ItemGroup element, it adds required packages -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz" Version="3.0.0-alpha2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz.Serialization.Json" Version="3.0.0-alpha2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

In the `Program` class (as scaffolded by Visual Studio by default):

```cs
public class Program
{
    private static IScheduler _scheduler; // add this field

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        StartScheduler(); // add this line

        host.Run();
    }

    // add this method
    private static void StartScheduler()
    {
        var properties = new NameValueCollection {
            // json serialization is the one supported under .NET Core (binary isn't)
            ["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json",

            // the following setup of job store is just for example and it didn't change from v2
            // according to your usage scenario though, you definitely need 
            // the ADO.NET job store and not the RAMJobStore.
            ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
            ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false",
            ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default",
            ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
            ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz",
            ["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-41", // SqlServer-41 is the new provider for .NET Core
            ["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = @"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Quartz;Integrated Security=true"
        };

        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        _scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
        _scheduler.Start().Wait();

        var userEmailsJob = JobBuilder.Create<SendUserEmailsJob>()
            .WithIdentity("SendUserEmails")
            .Build();
        var userEmailsTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("UserEmailsCron")
            .StartNow()
            .WithCronSchedule("0 0 17 ? * MON,TUE,WED")
            .Build();

        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(userEmailsJob, userEmailsTrigger).Wait();

        var adminEmailsJob = JobBuilder.Create<SendAdminEmailsJob>()
            .WithIdentity("SendAdminEmails")
            .Build();
        var adminEmailsTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("AdminEmailsCron")
            .StartNow()
            .WithCronSchedule("0 0 9 ? * THU,FRI")
            .Build();

        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(adminEmailsJob, adminEmailsTrigger).Wait();
    }
}
```

An example of a job class:

```cs
public class SendUserEmailsJob : IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // an instance of email service can be obtained in different ways, 
        // e.g. service locator, constructor injection (requires custom job factory)
        IMyEmailService emailService = new MyEmailService();

        // delegate the actual work to email service
        return emailService.SendUserEmails();
    }
}
```

### Full answer

#### Quartz for .NET Core

First, you have to use v3 of Quartz, as it targets .NET Core, according to [this announcement](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/2016/08/16/quartznet-3.0-alpha1-released.html).

Currently, only alpha versions of v3 packages are [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/3.0.0-alpha2). It looks like the team put a lot of effort into releasing 2.5.0, which does not target .NET Core. Nevertheless, in their GitHub repo, the `master` branch is already dedicated to v3, and basically, [open issues for v3 release](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/milestone/13) don't seem to be critical, mostly old wishlist items, IMHO. Since recent [commit activity](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/graphs/commit-activity) is quite low, I would expect v3 release in few months, or maybe half year - but no one knows.

#### Jobs and IIS recycling

If the web application is going to be hosted under IIS, you have to take into consideration recycling/unloading behavior of worker processes. The ASP.NET Core web app runs as a regular .NET Core process, separate from w3wp.exe - IIS only serves as a reverse proxy. Nevertheless, when an instance of w3wp.exe is recycled or unloaded, the related .NET Core app process is also signaled to exit (according to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1040)).

Web application can also be self-hosted behind a non-IIS reverse proxy (e.g. NGINX), but I will assume that you do use IIS, and narrow my answer accordingly.

The problems that recycling/unloading introduces are explained well in the [post referenced by @darin-dimitrov](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/):

- If for example, on Friday 9:00 the process is down, because several hours earlier it was unloaded by IIS due to inactivity - no admin emails will be sent until the process is up again. To avoid that, configure IIS to minimize unloads/recyclings ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38370392/4544845)).

  - From my experience, the above configuration still doesn't give a 100% guarantee that IIS will never unload the application. For 100% guarantee that your process is up, you can setup a command that periodically sends requests to your application, and thus keeps it alive.
- When the host process is recycled/unloaded, the jobs must be gracefully stopped, to avoid data corruption.

#### Why would you host scheduled jobs in a web app

I can think of one justification of having those email jobs hosted in a web app, despite the problems listed above. It is decision to have only one kind of application model (ASP.NET). Such approach simplifies learning curve, deployment procedure, production monitoring, etc.

If you don't want to introduce backend microservices (which would be a good place to move the email jobs to), then it makes sense to overcome IIS recycling/unloading behaviors, and run Quartz inside a web app.

Or maybe you have other reasons.

#### Persistent job store

In your scenario, status of job execution must be persisted out of process. Therefore, default *RAMJobStore* doesn't fit, and you have to use the *ADO.NET Job Store*.

Since you mentioned SQL Server in the question, I will provide example setup for SQL Server database.

#### How to start (and gracefully stop) the scheduler

I assume you use Visual Studio 2017 and latest/recent version of .NET Core tooling. Mine is .NET Core Runtime 1.1 and .NET Core SDK 1.0.

For DB setup example, I will use a database named `Quartz` in SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB. DB setup scripts can be [found here](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/database/tables).

First, add required package references to web application .csproj (or do it with NuGet package manager GUI in Visual Studio):

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <!-- .... existing contents .... -->

  <!-- the following ItemGroup adds required packages -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz" Version="3.0.0-alpha2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz.Serialization.Json" Version="3.0.0-alpha2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

With the help of [Migration Guide](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/migration-guide.html) and the [V3 Tutorial](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/index.html), we can figure out how to start and stop the scheduler. I prefer to encapsulate this in a separate class, let's name it `QuartzStartup`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    // Responsible for starting and gracefully stopping the scheduler.
    public class QuartzStartup
    {
        private IScheduler _scheduler; // after Start, and until shutdown completes, references the scheduler object

        // starts the scheduler, defines the jobs and the triggers
        public void Start()
        {
            if (_scheduler != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Already started.");
            }

            var properties = new NameValueCollection {
                // json serialization is the one supported under .NET Core (binary isn't)
                ["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json",

                // the following setup of job store is just for example and it didn't change from v2
                ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
                ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false",
                ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default",
                ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
                ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz",
                ["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-41", // SqlServer-41 is the new provider for .NET Core
                ["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = @"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Quartz;Integrated Security=true"
            };

            var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            _scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
            _scheduler.Start().Wait();

            var userEmailsJob = JobBuilder.Create<SendUserEmailsJob>()
                .WithIdentity("SendUserEmails")
                .Build();
            var userEmailsTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("UserEmailsCron")
                .StartNow()
                .WithCronSchedule("0 0 17 ? * MON,TUE,WED")
                .Build();

            _scheduler.ScheduleJob(userEmailsJob, userEmailsTrigger).Wait();

            var adminEmailsJob = JobBuilder.Create<SendAdminEmailsJob>()
                .WithIdentity("SendAdminEmails")
                .Build();
            var adminEmailsTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("AdminEmailsCron")
                .StartNow()
                .WithCronSchedule("0 0 9 ? * THU,FRI")
                .Build();

            _scheduler.ScheduleJob(adminEmailsJob, adminEmailsTrigger).Wait();
        }

        // initiates shutdown of the scheduler, and waits until jobs exit gracefully (within allotted timeout)
        public void Stop()
        {
            if (_scheduler == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // give running jobs 30 sec (for example) to stop gracefully
            if (_scheduler.Shutdown(waitForJobsToComplete: true).Wait(30000)) 
            {
                _scheduler = null;
            }
            else
            {
                // jobs didn't exit in timely fashion - log a warning...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note 1. In the above example, `SendUserEmailsJob` and `SendAdminEmailsJob` are classes that implement `IJob`. The `IJob` interface is slightly different from `IMyEmailService`, because it returns void `Task` and not `Task<bool>`. Both job classes should get `IMyEmailService` as a dependency (probably constructor injection).

Note 2. For a long-running job to be able to exit in timely fashion, in the `IJob.Execute` method, it should observe the status of `IJobExecutionContext.CancellationToken`. This may require change in `IMyEmailService` interface, to make its methods receive  `CancellationToken` parameter:

```cs
public interface IMyEmailService
{
    Task<bool> SendAdminEmails(CancellationToken cancellation);
    Task<bool> SendUserEmails(CancellationToken cancellation);
}
```

#### When and where to start and stop the scheduler

In ASP.NET Core, application bootstrap code resides in class `Program`, much like in console app. The `Main` method is called to create web host, run it, and wait until it exits:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

The simplest thing to do is just put a call to `QuartzStartup.Start` right in the `Main` method, much like as I did in TL;DR. But since we have to properly handle process shutdown as well, I prefer to hook both startup and shutdown code in a more consistent manner.

This line:

```
.UseStartup<Startup>()
```

refers to a class named `Startup`, which is scaffolded when creating new *ASP.NET Core Web Application* project in Visual Studio. The `Startup` class looks like this:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // scaffolded code...
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // scaffolded code...
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // scaffolded code...
    }
}
```

It is clear that a call to `QuartzStartup.Start` should be inserted in one of methods in the `Startup` class. The question is, where `QuartzStartup.Stop` should be hooked.

In the legacy .NET Framework, ASP.NET provided `IRegisteredObject` interface. According to [this post](https://shazwazza.com/post/aspnet-core-application-shutdown-events/), and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup), in ASP.NET Core it was replaced with `IApplicationLifetime`. Bingo. An instance of `IApplicationLifetime` can be injected into `Startup.Configure` method through a parameter.

For consistency, I will hook both `QuartzStartup.Start` and `QuartzStartup.Stop` to `IApplicationLifetime`:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app, 
        IHostingEnvironment env, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
        IApplicationLifetime lifetime) // added this parameter
    {
        // the following 3 lines hook QuartzStartup into web host lifecycle
        var quartz = new QuartzStartup();
        lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(quartz.Start);
        lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(quartz.Stop);

        // .... original scaffolded code here ....
    }

    // ....the rest of the scaffolded members ....
}
```

Note that I have extended the signature of the `Configure` method with an additional `IApplicationLifetime` parameter. According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime), `ApplicationStopping` will block until registered callbacks are completed.

#### Graceful shutdown on IIS Express, and ASP.NET Core module

I was able to observe expected behavior of `IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping` hook only on IIS, with the latest ASP.NET Core module installed. Both IIS Express (installed with Visual Studio 2017 Community RTM), and IIS with an outdated version of ASP.NET Core module didn't consistently invoke `IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping`. I believe it is because of [this bug](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/846) that was fixed.

You can install latest version of ASP.NET Core module [from here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule). Follow the instructions in the *"Installing the latest ASP.NET Core Module"* section.

#### Quartz vs. FluentScheduler

I also took a look at FluentScheduler, as it was proposed as an alternative library by @Brice Molesti. To my first impression, FluentScheduler is quite a simplistic and immature solution, compared to Quartz. For example, FluentScheduler doesn't provide such fundamental features as job status persistence and clustered execution.

Comment: Works with .net core 2.0 as well.

Comment: Works with .net core 2.1 as well.

Comment: I know it's not good to comment on an answer with "Well done", but seriously - well done, this contains a lot of valuable and needed information in one central place.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @felix-b answer. Adding DI to jobs. Also QuartzStartup Start can be made async.

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158004/1235390

```
public class QuartzStartup 
{
    public QuartzStartup(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        // other code is same
        _scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        _scheduler.JobFactory = new JobFactory(_serviceProvider);

        await _scheduler.Start();
        var sampleJob = JobBuilder.Create<SampleJob>().Build();
        var sampleTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().StartNow().WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?").Build();
        await _scheduler.ScheduleJob(sampleJob, sampleTrigger);
    }
}
```

JobFactory class

```
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public JobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        (job as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     // other code is removed for brevity
     // need to register all JOBS by their class name
     services.AddTransient<SampleJob>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    var quartz = new QuartzStartup(_services.BuildServiceProvider());
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => quartz.Start());
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(quartz.Stop);

    // other code removed for brevity
}
```

SampleJob class with contructor dependency injection:

```
public class SampleJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<SampleJob> _logger;

    public SampleJob(ILogger<SampleJob> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Execute called");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do it with Quartz, but i had experimented the same scenario with an other library wich works very well. Here how I dit it

- Install FluentScheduler

  ```
  Install-Package FluentScheduler
  ```
- Use it like this

  ```
  var registry = new Registry();
  JobManager.Initialize(registry);

  JobManager.AddJob(() => MyEmailService.SendAdminEmails(), s => s
        .ToRunEvery(1)
        .Weeks()
        .On(DayOfWeek.Monday)
        .At(17, 00));
  JobManager.AddJob(() => MyEmailService.SendAdminEmails(), s => s
        .ToRunEvery(1)
        .Weeks()
        .On(DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        .At(17, 00));

   JobManager.AddJob(() => MyEmailService.SendUserEmails(), s => s
         .ToRunEvery(1)
         .Weeks()
         .On(DayOfWeek.Thursday)
         .At(09, 00));

   JobManager.AddJob(() => MyEmailService.SendUserEmails(), s => s
         .ToRunEvery(1)
         .Weeks()
         .On(DayOfWeek.Friday)
         .At(09, 00));
  ```

Documentation can be found here [FluentScheduler on GitHub](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler)

Comment: Three things. (1) the documentation in the GitHub repo is outdated in regard to ASP.NET Core, (2) the above example should be hooked into web host, but you don't show how, (3) IMHO, a call to JobManager.StopAndBlock() is missing.

Comment: Hi, so to answer you : (1) In the documentation you have a part "Using it with .NET Core" (2) I'm currently using my example in .NET Core without additional configuration (I don't use DI here but you can) (3) I dynamically add job to this manager so if I stop and block, my scheduled jobs will not be executed (only ones currently running) and I can't schedule new one.

Comment: Hi @Brice, good points. Do you use it in ASP.NET Core application behind IIS reverse proxy, though? In general, the ASP.NET-Core-behind-IIS scenario requires proper handling of process unload initiated by AspNetCore IIS module. This is when JobManager.StopAndBlock() should be called. Yet, the documentation tells nothing about hooking into Kestrel server lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

> What code do I need to schedule these methods using Quartz in ASP.NET Core? I also need to know how to start Quartz in ASP.NET Core as all code samples on the internet still refer to previous versions of ASP.NET.

Hi, there is now a good quartz DI to initialize and use

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class Job1 : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<Job1> _logger;

    public Job1(ILogger<Job1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Start job1");
        await Task.Delay(2, context.CancellationToken);
        _logger?.LogInformation("End job1");
    }
}
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddQuartz(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory(opt =>
            {
                opt.AllowDefaultConstructor = false;
            });

            cfg.AddJob<Job1>(jobCfg =>
            {
                jobCfg.WithIdentity("job1");
            });

            cfg.AddTrigger(trigger =>
            {
                trigger
                    .ForJob("job1")
                    .WithIdentity("trigger1")
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                        .RepeatForever());
            });
        });

        services.AddQuartzHostedService(opt =>
        {
            opt.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // standart impl
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer covers the topic very well, but some things have changed with the latest Quartz version. The following is based on [this article](https://byteloom.marek-mierzwa.com/2017/04/13/scheduling-in-asp-net-core-with-quartz-net.html) shows a quick start with Quartz 3.0.x and ASP.NET Core 2.2:

#### Util class

```
public class QuartzServicesUtilities
{
    public static void StartJob<TJob>(IScheduler scheduler, TimeSpan runInterval)
        where TJob : IJob
    {
        var jobName = typeof(TJob).FullName;

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<TJob>()
            .WithIdentity(jobName)
            .Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity($"{jobName}.trigger")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(scheduleBuilder =>
                scheduleBuilder
                    .WithInterval(runInterval)
                    .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

#### Job factory

```
public class QuartzJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public QuartzJobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;

        var job = (IJob)_serviceProvider.GetService(jobDetail.JobType);
        return job;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job) { }
}
```

#### A job sample that also deals with exiting on application pool recycle / exit

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class TestJob : IJob
{
    private ILoggingService Logger { get; }
    private IApplicationLifetime ApplicationLifetime { get; }

    private static object lockHandle = new object();
    private static bool shouldExit = false;

    public TestJob(ILoggingService loggingService, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        Logger = loggingService;
        ApplicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
            {
                lock (lockHandle)
                {
                    shouldExit = true;
                }
            });

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
                {
                    lock (lockHandle)
                    {
                        if (shouldExit)
                        {
                            Logger.LogDebug($"TestJob detected that application is shutting down - exiting");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    Logger.LogDebug($"TestJob ran step {i+1}");
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Logger.LogError(exc, "An error occurred during execution of scheduled job");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Startup.cs configuration

```
private void ConfigureQuartz(IServiceCollection services, params Type[] jobs)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, QuartzJobFactory>();
    services.Add(jobs.Select(jobType => new ServiceDescriptor(jobType, jobType, ServiceLifetime.Singleton)));

    services.AddSingleton(provider =>
    {
        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
        scheduler.JobFactory = provider.GetService<IJobFactory>();
        scheduler.Start();
        return scheduler;
    });
}

protected void ConfigureJobsIoc(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ConfigureQuartz(services, typeof(TestJob), /* other jobs come here */);
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ConfigureJobsIoc(services);

    // other stuff comes here
    AddDbContext(services);
    AddCors(services);

    services
        .AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}


protected void StartJobs(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    var scheduler = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IScheduler>();
    //TODO: use some config
    QuartzServicesUtilities.StartJob<TestJob>(scheduler, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

    lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => scheduler.Start());
    lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => scheduler.Shutdown());
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    ILoggingService logger, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    StartJobs(app, lifetime);

    // other stuff here
}
```

Comment: I guess QuartzServicesUtilities is the one found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55211511/quartz-net-3-0-seems-to-launch-all-jobs-in-the-same-scope

Comment: Yes, that should be it. Thanks.