# Using FluentScheduler - ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, fluentscheduler

I currently have a simple website setup with ASP.NET Core MVC (.NET 4.6.1), and I would like to periodically do some processes like automatically send emails at the end of every day to the registered members.

After doing some searching, I came across two common solutions - Quartz.NET and FluentScheduler.

Based on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821568/how-to-start-quartz-in-asp-net-core), I found the approach of using FluentScheduler more easier to digest and use for my simple task. After quickly implementing the following lines of code into my Program.cs class, I had the emails going out successfully every minute (for testing purposes).

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

            var registry = new Registry();
            JobManager.Initialize(registry);

            JobManager.AddJob(() => MyEmailService.SendEmail(), s => s
                  .ToRunEvery(1)
                  .Minutes());

            host.Run();

    }
}
```

However, now apart from sending emails I also need to do some back-end processing for e.g. updating the user records in the DB when mails are being sent out. For this, I normally inject my Entity Framework Context into the constructor of my controllers and use it to get/update SQL records.

My question is, since I cannot really inject these services into the main method, where would be the appropriate place to initialize the registry and add jobs for scheduling?

Thanks for the help, I am a little new to this so a little guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of Program's Main function, I initialized the same in Startup.cs before app.UseMvc..

```
public void Configure(...., IDependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
           ....
           JobManager.Initialize(new MyRegistry(dependencyObject));

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            });
}
```

My registry class looks like this:

```
public class MyRegistry: Registry
{
    public MyRegistry(IDependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {            
        Schedule(() => new SyncUpJob(dependencyObject)).ToRunNow().AndEvery(10).Seconds();
    }
}
```

My Job class looks like this:

```
public class SyncUpJob: IJob
{
    public SyncUpJob(IDependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        DependencyObject= dependencyObject;
    }

    public IDependencyObject DependencyObject{ get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        // call the method to run weekly here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define all your jobs and their schedules, by subclassing from FluentScheduler `Registry` class. something like:

```
public class JobRegistry : Registry {

    public JobRegistry() {
        Schedule<EmailJob>().ToRunEvery(1).Days();
        Schedule<SomeOtherJob>().ToRunEvery(1).Seconds();
    }

}

public class EmailJob : IJob {

    public DbContext Context { get; } // we need this dependency, right?!

    public EmailJob(DbContext context) //constructor injection
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        //Job implementation code: send emails to users and update database
    }
}
```

For injecting dependencies into jobs, you need to implement FluentScheduler `IJobFactory` interface. `GetJobIntance` method is called by FluentScheduler for creating job instances. Here you can use any DI library you want; In this sample implementation, I'm going to assume that you use Ninject:

```
public class MyNinjectModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<DbContext>().To<MyDbContextImplemenation>();
    }
}

public class JobFactory : IJobFactory {

    private IKernel Kernel { get; }

    public JobFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        Kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IJob GetJobInstance<T>() where T : IJob
    {
        return Kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

Now you can start your jobs in main method by calling:

```
JobManager.JobFactory = new JobFactory(new StandardKernel(new MyNinjectModule()));
JobManager.Initialize(new JobRegistry());
```