# DependencyInjection issue during using FluentScheduler in .NET Core API application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, fluentscheduler

I want to update data in my database each hour. So, I find good [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler) library for this and create my `IJob`:

```
public class InfoLoader : IJob
{
    private readonly DataContext _db;

    public InfoLoader(DataContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        foreach (User user in _db.Users.ToList())
        {
            foreach (Info i in user.Info.ToList())
            {
                UpdateInfo(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateInfo(Info info)
    {
        // do some operations to update information in db
    }
}
```

And of course I create my `Registry` implementation to schedule all tasks which I need:

```
public class LoadersRegistry : Registry
{
    public LoadersRegistry()
    {
        Schedule<InfoLoader>().ToRunNow().AndEvery(1).Hours();
    }
}
```

Also I add following code in my Program.cs file to initalize scheduler and start it:

```
JobManager.JobException += (obj) => { logger.LogError(obj.Exception.Message); };
JobManager.Initialize(new LoadersRegistry());
```

But when I run my application I see following error:

[image: Running app]

I understand that `LoadersRegistry` can't create instance of `InfoLoader` (during `JobManger` initializes it in `Program.cs`), because `InfoLoader` receives `DataContext`. But I can't do not receive `DataContext`, because I need it to add data in my database.

Unfortunately I can't find a way to fix this issue.

Thanks for any help.

P.S. I read about [using FluentScheduler in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260493/using-fluentscheduler-asp-net-core-mvc), but developers of this library said that this feature [will not be available in the future](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler#dependency-injection) because of [this](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler/issues/71#issuecomment-307287249), so I still don't know how I can solve the issue.

Comment: FYI - Background scheduling is [built-in to .NET Core 2.x](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/), there is no need to use a 3rd party library for it.

Comment: thanks, I start reading the article you specify! :)

Comment: @NightOwl888, it requires a lot of code to create own `IHostedService` to schedule task, so I will be happy to solve this small problem instead of re-write this part of project to use `IHostedService`.

Answer (score 2):

As per the API document you'll have to change the way you register. 
Following is just one way of doing it.

```
public LoadersRegistry()
    {
        var dataContext = new DataContext();
        Schedule(()=> new InfoLoader(dataContext)).ToRunNow().AndEvery(1).Hours();
    }
```

Here I'm doing new DataContext() but you could make dataContext available however you like as long as you are newing up InfoLoader with it.

Answer (score 1):

If someone will meet with similar issue, this is solution which helps me:

You just need to do initialization inside `Startup.cs` file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    JobManager.Initialize(new LoadersRegistry(
        provider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>()
    ));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

And of course, `LoadersRegistry` should receive `DataContext` instance, and `InfoLoader` should receive this instance in constructor:

```
public LoadersRegistry(DataContext db)
{
    Schedule(new InfoLoader(db)).ToRunNow().AndEvery(30).Seconds();
}
```

Good luck! :)