# Delete a User after Email Confirmation token expires in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a requirement to automatically delete a user in Identity after their email validation token expires. I need help on how to handle such behavior. Is there a way I can somehow catch the event and put in my delete user code? Please help.

Comment: No event is raised when the token expires since that's only a field in the database. You would need to create a job that continually pulls the users that must be deleted manually

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you will need a way to handle this. One good option is to setup a Serverless function that checks for this condition on a regular interval. Not sure how you plan to publish but this here is an intro for Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/.

If you don't want to do something like that then you need to decide if you want to do this on the application layer or the database layer. For example if you want to do this in the application layer you can use a Quartz here is some info on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058170/7446265

Comment: Thanks for your response. I came up with a thought of running a background process to do the operation. I am using hangfire for the background job. I hope asp.net considers such scenarios where they will make provision for custom extensions to perform special requirements like mine

Comment: Np. It is one of those fuzzy areas on API's in general. I would like to see better ways to handle it myself.