# Quartz.NET 3.0 seems to launch all jobs in the same scope

Tags: c#, quartz.net, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a hard time using Quartz 3.0.7 with ASP.NET Core 2.2 after I have defined two jobs that rely on a scoped service (ScopedDataAccess) that is a wrapper upon my database context:

```
services.AddScoped<IScopedDataAccess, ScopedDataAccess>();

services.AddDbContext<AggregatorContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
```

The issue is that both jobs receive the same instance of the scoped service (and thus the same database context), thus crashing the context due to parallel usage.

My code is as follows:

#### Startup.cs

Jobs are defined as "scoped" and my expectation is for each instance to run in its own "scope"

```
private void ConfigureQuartz(IServiceCollection services, params Type[] jobs)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, QuartzJobFactory>();
    services.Add(jobs.Select(jobType => new ServiceDescriptor(jobType, jobType, ServiceLifetime.Scoped)));

    services.AddSingleton(provider =>
    {
        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;

        scheduler.JobFactory = provider.GetService<IJobFactory>();
        scheduler.Start();
        return scheduler;
    });
}

protected void StartJobs(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    var scheduler = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IScheduler>();
    var configService = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IConfigurationService>();

    QuartzServicesUtilities.StartJob<ArticleXUserDataRefresherJob>(scheduler, 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(configService.ArticleXUserDataRefresherJobPeriod));
    QuartzServicesUtilities.StartJob<LinkDataFetchJob>(scheduler,
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(configService.LinkDataJobPeriod));

    lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => scheduler.Start());
    lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => scheduler.Shutdown());
}
```

#### QuartzServicesUtilities

```
public class QuartzServicesUtilities
{
    public static void StartJob<TJob>(IScheduler scheduler, TimeSpan runInterval)
        where TJob : IJob
    {
        var jobName = typeof(TJob).FullName;

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<TJob>()
            .WithIdentity(jobName)
            .Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity($"{jobName}.trigger")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(scheduleBuilder =>
                scheduleBuilder
                    .WithInterval(runInterval)
                    .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

#### QuartzJobFactory

```
public class QuartzJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public QuartzJobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;

        var job = (IJob)_serviceProvider.GetService(jobDetail.JobType);
        return job;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job) { }
}
```

Is there a way to use Quartz.NET to obtain different scopes for different jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i know, this is not possible with Quartz, i struggled with the same issues and the only solution i found was to use a ServiceLocator and create the scope explicitly in the Job.

I ended with something like that:

```
// Pseudo-Code
public class MyJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IServiceLocator _serviceLocator;

    public MyJob(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
    {
        _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
    }

    public async Task Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        using(_serviceLocator.BeginScope())
        {
            var worker = _serviceLocator.GetService<MyWorker>();
            await worker.DoWorkAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, your worker is still scoped but the job isn't anymore. So you can still use your Worker in other places in your solution and the scope still works.
You need to implement the ServiceLocator by yourself depending on the DI do you use and `IServiceLocator` must also be defined by you.

**Edit**

In one of our projects we use this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A simple service locator to hide the real IOC Container.
/// Lowers the anti-pattern of service locators a bit.
/// </summary>
public interface IServiceLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Begins an new async scope.
    /// The scope should be disposed explicitly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>

    IDisposable BeginAsyncScope();
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an instance of the given <typeparamref name="TService" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TService">Type of the requested service.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The requested service instance.</returns>
    TService GetInstance<TService>() where TService : class;
}
```

We use mostly SimpleInjector with this implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// SimpleInjector implementation of the service locator.
/// </summary>
public class ServiceLocator : IServiceLocator
{
    #region member vars

    /// <summary>
    /// The SimpleInjector container.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Container _container;

    #endregion

    #region constructors and destructors

    public ServiceLocator(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    #endregion

    #region explicit interfaces

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IDisposable BeginAsyncScope()
    {
        return AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_container);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public TService GetInstance<TService>()
        where TService : class
    {
        return _container.GetInstance<TService>();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is just a simple wrapper but helps to hide the real DI Framework from the consumers.
I hope this helps a little bit to understand your needed implementation.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I keep jobs as scoped (`services.Add(jobs.Select(jobType => new ServiceDescriptor(jobType, jobType, ServiceLifetime.Scoped)));`) and use a service locator to create a separate scope. I use built in DI, but it is not clear how to implement ServiceLocator service. I have searched and I have found locating services based on HttpContext.ApplicationServices. but HttpContext is not available in this context (it is not related to any request).

Comment: I will test proposed solution once I figure out about the service locator. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexei The jobs are not longer scoped because you don't need it if you open the scope and resolve the services by hand.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. I will retry provided implementation and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Since I am not using SimpleInjector, I have created a static reference in Startup.cs which I use it to create a new scope for each job: `QuartzScopedProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider()` and the service locator will use this to create new scopes: `_serviceScope = Startup.QuartzScopedProvider.CreateScope();`. Does it make sense? Anyway, your answer really made me understand how things work.