# Quartz.net 3 trigger fires another job

Tags: c#, .net-core, quartz.net

I am setting up quartz.net 3.0.7 to my .net core 2.2 app. Everything works flawlessly if I have ony one job added to the "services". However, when I add a second job. The trigger of the first job somehow triggers the second job.

My extension methods for quartz:

```
public static void AddQuartz(this IServiceCollection services, string configuration)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, ScheduledJobFactory>();

    var properties = new NameValueCollection
    {
        ["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json",
        ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
        ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false",
        ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "sqlserver",
        ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
        ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz",
        //["quartz.dataSource.sqlserver.provider"] = "SqlServer-41", // SqlServer-41 is the new provider for .NET Core
        ["quartz.dataSource.sqlserver.provider"] = "SqlServer",
        ["quartz.dataSource.sqlserver.connectionString"] = configuration
    };
    services.AddSingleton<IScheduler>(provider =>
    {
        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
        scheduler.JobFactory = provider.GetService<IJobFactory>();
        //scheduler.ScheduleJob(JobTrigger);
        return scheduler;
    });

}

public static void AddJob(this IServiceCollection services, Type job)
{
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IJob), job, ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
}

public static void StartRepetitiveJob<TJob>(this IScheduler scheduler, TimeSpan runInterval, DateTimeOffset startWhen) where TJob : IJob
{
    var jobName = typeof(TJob).FullName;

    var job = JobBuilder.Create<TJob>()
        .WithIdentity(jobName,jobName)
        .StoreDurably()
        .Build();

    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity($"{jobName}.trigger", $"{jobName}.trigger")
        .StartAt(startWhen)
        .WithSimpleSchedule(scheduleBuilder =>
            scheduleBuilder
                .WithInterval(runInterval)
                .RepeatForever())
                .ForJob(job)
        .Build();

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}

public static void FireJobOnlyOnce<TJob>(this IScheduler scheduler, DateTime fireat, IDictionary<string, object> dictionary) where TJob : IJob
{
    var jobName = typeof(TJob).FullName;
    var jobDataMap = new JobDataMap(dictionary);
    var job = JobBuilder.Create<TJob>()
        .WithIdentity(jobName,jobName)
        //.WithIdentity(jobName, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        .SetJobData(jobDataMap)
        .StoreDurably()
        .Build();

    var trigger = (ISimpleTrigger) TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity($"{jobName}.trigger", $"{jobName}.trigger")
        .StartAt(fireat.ToUniversalTime()) 
        .UsingJobData(jobDataMap)
        .ForJob(job)
        .Build();
    scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

in **startup.cs**:

```
services.AddQuartz(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        services.AddJob(typeof(CheckPropertyListingJob));
        services.AddJob(typeof(ScheduledGetPropertyDataJob));
```

in **program.cs**:

```
            DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(6);
        scheduler.StartRepetitiveJob<CheckPropertyListingJob>(interval, new DateTimeOffset(dt.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)), TimeSpan.Zero));
```

So, when I add only the `CheckPropertyListingJob`, everything is fine. But when I add the `ScheduledGetPropertyDataJob` somehow the created trigger for `CheckPropertyListingJob` fires the other job.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally solved the issue. I started to implement quartz following a tutorial with only one job. So my ScheduledJobFactory looked like this:

```
    public class ScheduledJobFactory: IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public ScheduledJobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IJob)) as IJob;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        var disposable = job as IDisposable;
        disposable?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I edited the NewJob method depending on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55176009/7060914) and everything is fine. I cannot believe I can be so unobservant.

```
            return (IJob)serviceProvider.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
```